# Generate a fixed-length pulse on a pin with Betaflight

Tags: betaflight

I have a small camcoder module with a very simple interface: it has a 3.3V trigger pin controlled by an active LOW pulse which is used to start and stop the recording. The pulse has to be in the range 0.2..0.4s, otherwise it is ignored.

[image]

I know I can drive a pin using [PINIO](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/wiki/Pinio-and-PinioBox), but that means I'll have to toggle the switch ON and OFF in a timely manner to generate the pulse. Since there's no feedback from the camcoder (I cannot know if it's recording or not), generating pulses in such a way is unacceptable.

How can I instruct Betaflight to produce the complete pulse (ON and OFF edges) when an AUX channel is in a certain range?