# Hysteresis and debounce of modes in Betaflight

Tags: betaflight

Is there a way to apply hysteresis and debounce delay to an arbitrary [mode](https://github.com/betaflight/betaflight/blob/master/docs/Modes.md) in Betaflight? I'm especially interested in doing this for user modes, in order to achieve functionalities such as [this one](https://drones.stackexchange.com/questions/2451/generate-a-fixed-length-pulse-on-a-pin-with-betaflight).

Hysteresis example: the mode is activated when the channel value is between 1500 and 1700, and stays activated until the value goes out of range (1400 ... 1900).

Debounce example: once activated, the mode stays on for 1 second, even if the channel value goes out of range immediately. Once deactivated, the mode stays off for 0.5 seconds, even if the channel value goes in the activation range again.

Comment: These all sound like things that should be done on the transmitter side, not on the flight controller side. Any radio transmitter running openTX would be able to do this, if not through programming (there's a guy somewhere on youtube that specifically takes on challenges like this), through a lua script.